# Calculate Mean By Two Columns in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Given the df extract below, how can I calculate the mean Prob per SelectionId per MarketId?

I thought this would work but it doesn't:

```
df.groupby(['MarketId', 'SelectionId', ], as_index=False)['Prob'].mean()
```

Example df:-

|  | Time | MarketId | SelectionId | Prob |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 06/01/2016 19:58:01 | 1.12211769 | 56343 | 3.3 |
| 1 | 06/01/2016 19:58:01 | 1.12211769 | 47999 | 2.34 |
| 2 | 06/01/2016 19:58:01 | 1.12211769 | 58805 | 3.8 |
| 3 | 06/01/2016 19:59:01 | 1.12211769 | 56343 | 3.2 |
| 4 | 06/01/2016 19:59:01 | 1.12211769 | 47999 | 2.3 |
| 5 | 06/01/2016 19:59:01 | 1.12211769 | 58805 | 3.8 |
| 6 | 06/01/2016 20:00:01 | 1.12211769 | 56343 | 3.2 |
| 7 | 06/01/2016 20:00:01 | 1.12211769 | 47999 | 2.34 |
| 8 | 06/01/2016 20:00:01 | 1.12211769 | 58805 | 3.8 |
| 9 | 15/06/2016 18:59:43 | 1.122271208 | 24 | 1.25 |
| 10 | 15/06/2016 18:59:43 | 1.122271208 | 15285 | 19 |
| 11 | 15/06/2016 18:59:43 | 1.122271208 | 58805 | 6.6 |
| 12 | 15/06/2016 19:01:43 | 1.122271208 | 24 | 1.26 |
| 13 | 15/06/2016 19:01:43 | 1.122271208 | 15285 | 18 |
| 14 | 15/06/2016 19:01:43 | 1.122271208 | 58805 | 6.8 |
| 15 | 15/06/2016 19:02:43 | 1.122271208 | 24 | 1.27 |
| 16 | 15/06/2016 19:02:43 | 1.122271208 | 15285 | 19 |
| 17 | 15/06/2016 19:02:43 | 1.122271208 | 58805 | 6.6 |

### Desired df:

|  | MarketId | SelectionId | Prob |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.12211769 | 56343 | 3.233 |
| 1 | 1.12211769 | 47999 | 2.326 |
| 2 | 1.12211769 | 58805 | 3.8 |
| 3 | 1.122271208 | 24 | 1.26 |
| 4 | 1.122271208 | 15285 | 18.667 |
| 5 | 1.122271208 | 58805 | 6.667 |

Comment: but the expression above gives you the desired df you posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a comma too much in your list of columns. And you need to use reset_inde()

```
df.groupby(['MarketId', 'SelectionId'])['Prob'].mean().reset_index()
```

Edit
Okay, it was just the comma.